# PHP - WordPress Script To Get Random Line From Text File

Tags: php, random, wordpress

Good day. I have a WordPress plugin script here that as below works fine in doing what it should. What I am having trouble with is editing/appending the script to do one additional task that I need. What the plugin does is setup a category in WordPress and then every hour go get a video from Youtube and create a post on the blog.

So for example, if I typed in create category: Siberian Husky's then that category would be created and every hour the script will go get a new video title, video embed and description related to Siberian Husky's.

**(How the title is created now with the script ->)** Let's say the first video it get's the title on Youtube is this: White Siberian Husky's Are Loveable

That would be the title to the WordPress post. What I want to do is place a text file on in my sites root directory called /phrases.txt and on each line would be a new phrase. I want this script to go get randomly a new phrase from that text file and put it "in front" of the Youtube title.

**(How I want the output to be after getting a random line from my text file ->)** So when the post is made on the blog the title would be: Here Is My Phrase From Text File : White Sibeian Husky's Are Loveable

I hope I made that clear enough. Below is the entire script that get's the data for the video post on the blog.

I believe around line 1861 is where the script writes the title, don't quote me, I am not positive. That part of the code looks like:

```
// and create a post
        $wpvt_post = array(
            'post_title' => $content->items[0]->snippet->title,
            'post_content' => $post_content,
            'post_author' => $item['item']['post_author'],
            'post_status' => $item['item']['post_status'],
        );
```

Where the ->title, is creates the title for the post. I am not sure what to change or add to have the script go to my text file and get my phrase I want to add to the title.

Here is a link to the entire script --> http://textuploader.com/kg8m

It was to large to paste into this post, sorry.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it working my code matt..? then don't forget to add right mark on Answer ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had not added in wordpress code here but still in PHP code it's working fine for me you had just add to this code in wordpress format. As per wordpress query and all those things.

code is here.

`<?php
    $f_contents = file("random.txt"); 
    $line = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
?>`

Comment: Another Options is that is it also working for me.
`<?php
$f_contents = file("testfile.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand ($f_contents)];
echo $line;
?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Pull out a random quote from the quote file and display it. 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
function random_phrase () 
{ 
$quotes = file ("wp-content/quotes.txt");
$num = rand (0, intval (count ($quotes) / 3)) * 3;
echo $quotes[$num] . "<br>" . $quotes[$num + 1];
}
?>
Now just put this little bit of code where you want the quote to appear:
<?php random_phrase (); ?>
```

Comment: I put the top php code at the top of my script and I put random_phrase in like this: 'post_title' => $content->items[0]->snippet->random_phrase->title, but the post comes up with an empty title.